# What's wrong with my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm testing this function in JavaScript Console of FireFox on this website:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=python
And Desired output is just text (.innerHTML) of each link.

```
    parents = document.getElementsByClassName("r");
    function my_links() {
        links = {};
        for (var i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {
            links[i] = parents[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        };
        return links;
    }
    elements = my_links();
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        g_link = elements[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(g_link + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: What is `MyClass.js_showMessage("Result");`?

Comment: What exceptions do you get when running that code? What does not work?

Comment: -1 Please take the time to try to isolate the problem/issue enough to at least write a useful title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("r");
function my_links() {
    var links = []; // <-- I suppose it should be array and should not be global
    for (var i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {
        // when you're not defining array length then use push instead of indexes
        links.push(parents[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0]);
    };
    return links;
}
```

you can do this in more efficient way

```
function my_links() {
     var links = new Array(parents.length),
         i = parents.length;
     while (i--) {
         links[i] = parents[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     }
     return links;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for improving my code

Answer (score 3):

You did assign an empty *object* to the `links` variable, but as you access its `length` property later on I guess you'd expect it to be an *array*. Change it to

```
    links = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `links` (and so `elements`) is an object, not an array, so you can't get its length. You can change it to an array (it is probably what you wanted to do, `links=[]` instead of `links = {}`) or you can use foreach loop to log all properties of the`elements` object:

```
for (i in elements) {
    g_link = elements[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(g_link + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Please distinguish between for-in-loops and for-each-loops - they are a different thing in coming EcmaScript versions. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot for pointing this! Very Appreciate it!